# Reporting marginal/borderline/almost not significant, yet significant effects

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, trend, reporting

I have a figure as follows. Confidence intervals are only slightly bounded away from each other at the edges. Thus, $x$ seems to have an association with $y$.

How would you describe such an effect? Like every other significant effect or should I be more cautious while interpreting the relationship. For example, there was a borderline effect of $x$ on $y$?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the intervals overlap on all $x$-values?

Comment: Good point, i edited the original post to correct that mistake.

Comment: I don’t mean to belabor the point, but what do you mean when you say the interval(s) overlap? Do you mean that the interval is bounded *away from* zero, but not by a lot? If you could provide further clarity it would be helpful.

Comment: You can have some overlap, but still have a significant difference. I would bet dollars to donuts that you could reject the null that the expected values are the same at the two edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the intervals overlap in between the range of your data, but not at the edges. As a general rule, if your 95% confidence intervals at the extremes are bounded away from each other (i.e., no overlap), then your estimate of the difference will be deemed statistically significant by conventional standards. However, the converse is not likely to always be true. Thus, at the edges you could also have some marginal degree of overlap and still find a "significant" effect.

A downward trend is apparent, but the effect of $x$ on $y$ is marginal. As a visual heuristic, if a straight, horizontal line can fit within the error ribbon, then the effect is not significant. As indicated in your post, your effect *is*, in fact, significant. I would recommend being transparent about the relationship. For instance, try reporting your $p$-value as an *equality* (e.g., $p = 0.499$) rather than an *in*equality (e.g., $p < 0.05)$. Doing so will make the "borderline effect" appear less pronounced (see, e.g., [Wasserstein et al. 2019](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2019.1583913)).

In sum, yes, it is safe to report this as a marginally significant, downward sloping trend, but I would be transparent about the degree of overlap, if any, you are observing.